# Rails - creating a new model and error "uninitialized constant"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I created a new table (through a migration) and then I manually added a model - the model looks like this:

```
class UserData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.save_user_data(data, cur_user)
    data.each do |d|
      puts "Saving: #{cur_user.id}, #{d['id']}, #{d['name']}"
      UserData.create!(:user_id => cur_user.id,
                       :name => d['name'])
    end
  end
end
```

The table is properly created.

I call this method from **/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb** like this:

```
UserData.save_user_data(@data, current_user) if @data
```

And getting this error:

```
uninitialized constant Users::OmniauthCallbacksController::UserData
```

What am I missing in this case?

Comment: Are you using scopes in your project? Sounds to me like Rails tries to find the `UserData` class underneath the `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController` namespace...

Comment: No, I don't (I am not very familiar with scopes, that's why I don't use them).

Answer (score 3):

Try using `::UserData` instead of `UserData` in your controller class.

Comment: I've tried, but got a different error message. However, I found the problem - the file with model was named **user_datas.rb** instead of **user_data.rb**. I need some sleep.